# Using Vemto Laravel code generator with Laravel 9 and cannot later edit in VSCode

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I am using latest Vemto code generator to generate Laravel 9 code successfully. However, it is then impossible to edit this code using VSCode editor as the CLI throws errors indicating there is no json file in the directory and it cannot find artisan. Clearly there are files missing in comparison with a regular Laravel install - `composer create-project laravel/laravel whaterever_proj`

Is there a way around this problem? How do I add the necessary files to the poject directory in order to get artisan etc. to run in my Vempto project? All help, advice or guidance gratefully received. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here's the problem in detail:

A project is generated in Vempto - without errors.
Subsequently the code [for some reason] needs modifying, editing or updating - say a new number of posts or uses are required...
If the project is re-generated in Vempto, then any previous code edits done directly in the files will be lost by regeneration.
So, Vempto is excellent for primary scaffolding of a project but, which leads to my question, ...

Comment: How is it possible to inculcate basic Laravel & artisan into the project directory generated by Vempto such that is becomes possible to run Laravel artisan commands?
If this is tried, the CLI returns the JSON config file cannot be found. If one is provided then artisan cannot be found etc., etc.
So, how may these files be added to the original Vemto generation and what files are required.
I hope that makes the problem clear. If not, I will provide a practical example. Thank you for your interest and assistance.